# Issue with cp when copying exe files in Msys2 or Git Bash in Windows

Tags: windows, git-bash, msys2, git-for-windows

I came across a weird issue with `cp` in Git Bash, and same for Msys2 shell. When copying an `exe` file (e.g., `some-file.exe`) along with a file with the same name but no extension (e.g., `some-file`), it will only copy `some-file` but as the name `some-file.exe`.  Here are the steps to reproduce.

```bash
mkdir a-new-tmp-folder
cd a-new-tmp-folder
mkdir tmp
echo "file" >file
echo "file.exe" >file.exe
cp -t tmp file.exe file
ls tmp              # only `file.exe' there
cat tmp/file.exe    # shows `file' instead of expected `file.exe'
```

However, if swap the last 2 arguments of cp (`cp -t tmp file file.exe`), there won't be any issue.  Could anyone please help explain?

Comment: Strange. Try --target-directory=DIRECTORY and see if it does the same thing

Comment: It's entirely possible that `cp` commands for Windows might treat an executable file without a `.exe` extension as equivalent to the same name with a `.exe` appended.  This would be a somewhat awkward adaptation to the fact that DOS and traditional Windows shells evaluate whether a file is executable based on the form of its name, not based on metadata.

Comment: If that's what's happening then you might be able to work around it by copying the files separately, giving a destination path that includes the filename.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Msys2 todo list](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Devtopics/#fix-pacman-errors-wrt-conflicts-in-binfoo-vs-binfooexe), this is a known issue because *the runtime emulates extension-less executables by also looking for `.exe` on various FS calls*.

It seems that there is currently no solution or workaround for this issue.

> ### Fix pacman errors wrt. conflicts in `bin/foo` vs `bin/foo.exe`
>
> The runtime emulates extension-less executables by also looking for `.exe` on various FS calls. (There are more of these hacks, for example for symlink emulation.) This is causing pacman to complain when two packages independently provide both `foo` and `foo.exe`, or even worse `dir/` and `dir.exe`. People have to either disregard these conflicts with `--force` or (re-)install packages in a specific order.
>
> A possible solution to these conflicts would be to disable the .exe interpolation, but then something would break, either users wouldn't be able to either run MSYS2 executables directly from Windows, or couldn't use the short extension-less names of commands in MSYS2.